# Spark - Select sum and all columns of joined dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables Employees (Id, Name), EmployeeSalary (EmployeeId, Designation, Salary). One employee can hold multiple designations in the company and have multiple salaries. How do I get EmployeeId, Name, Sum of salaries, Seq of all designations.

What I tried so far is

```
    employeeDS.join(employeeSalaryDS, employeeDS.col("Id")
.equalTo(employeeSalaryDS.col("EmployeeId")),"left_outer")
.groupBy(employeeDS.col("Id")).agg(sum("Salary") as "Sum of salaries")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
scala> val dfe = Seq((101,"John"),(102,"Mike"), (103,"Paul"), (104,"Tom")).toDF("id","name")
dfe: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, name: string]

scala> val dfes = Seq((101,"Dev", 4000),(102,"Designer", 4000),(102,"Architect", 5000), (103,"Designer",6000), (104,"Consultant",8000), (104,"Supervisor",9000), (104,"PM",10000) ).toDF("id","desig","salary")
dfes: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, desig: string ... 1 more field]

scala> dfe.join(dfes, dfe.col("id").equalTo(dfes.col("id")),"left_outer").groupBy(dfe.col("Id")).agg(sum("Salary") as "Sum of salaries", collect_list('desig as "desig_list")).show(false)
+---+---------------+-----------------------------------+
|Id |Sum of salaries|collect_list(desig AS `desig_list`)|
+---+---------------+-----------------------------------+
|101|4000           |[Dev]                              |
|103|6000           |[Designer]                         |
|102|9000           |[Architect, Designer]              |
|104|27000          |[PM, Supervisor, Consultant]       |
+---+---------------+-----------------------------------+


scala>
```

Comment: This works. How about if I want to select the whole EmployeeSalary table

Comment: Not getting you.. the above join uses the entire salary table without any filter

Comment: The collect_list selects only one column here. What change would be required for selecting the whole EmployeeSalary table (with designation and salary both)

Comment: In that case you need to store the above in a separate ds and join with salary table again.  Use window functions to get the results.